# Currency Values Pasted From Firefox Becomes Text in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel, firefox, microsoft-excel-2003

New here. This is a commonly asked question but cannot seem to find the answer specific to my issue.

Just got a refurbished computer Windows 7 Professional 32bit. Installed Office 2003 and Firefox 41.0.2. One of my regular tasks is to copy rows of data from a web page and paste it into Excel. Some of the cells become merged but all appear as in the original web page EXCEPT for the last cell (also a merged cell). This cell contains a currency value. When pasted into Excel, it becomes text, and cannot be used for calculations. The cell in Excel is formatted as Currency, but after pasting, becomes Text.

Example : $4.90 pasted into Excel LOOKS like $4.90 but the value INCLUDES the "$" sign.

My other computers don't have this problem. I have tried almost all the other solutions found on the web eg. converting the cells to numbers, paste special with multiply by a cell containing the value 1 etc.

I've found that after pasting the data, if I just delete the "$" sign, it works fine.

Comment: In the `Format Cell` settings did you specify a symbol for the currency?

Comment: yes. It's formatted as Currency (2 decimal places). Have tried changing to Number but also the same - Currency Data becomes text.

Comment: So the problem then seems to be that Excel uses $ (as the first char) as absolute reference to a column. So when you copy-paste something with that character in that position, Excel doesn't really understand what it's meant to be and hence cannot convert it properly to a currency sign. The problem doesn't appear with e.g the euro sign (€), since it's at the end of the value. I'll take a look around to see if I can figure out something better than to remove the $ for every cell.

Comment: Seems to work OK in LibreOffice Calc. And what are the "other computers"? Not Windows 7?

Comment: One is a Windows XP machine (SP2). 
The other is a Windows 7 machine, but running Office 2010. 
The machine with the problem is a refurbished unit I just bought, running Windows 7 Professional and Office 2003. I've almost resigned myself to having to delete the "$" sign from this column for the rest of my life!!!!

Comment: I would guess that Office 2003 is doing it. Try switching to LibreOffice or a more recent version of Office as a test. Also, in the OS you might check regional settings to see if there are any selected languages or regional formats other than English.

Comment: Cant switch to higher version. The laptop running Office 2010 sold to me as is - came installed with Office 2010. So I can't install it in this machine, otherwise, I would have. However, the paste works okay in the machine with the office 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem. Wasn't an Excel or Firefox issue.

Excel defaulted the currency symbol to my country's local currency (RM Malaysia) because this was the default setting when Windows 7 was installed. So the solution was to change the setting :

Control Panel > Region & Language > Formats Tab (Additional Settings) > Currency Tab > Changed (Local Currency RM) to $.

All is okay now.

I hope. ;-)